# allow only specific escape characters in regular expression

Tags: regex, grammar, antlr4

I have been looking through other `regex` questions, but have not been able to find an answer. I am working on a grammar in ANTLR4 and there is a regular expression that has been eluding me.

I am trying to match any character, **except** for `\` followed by anything other than `[btnrf"\]`.

I have tried `( ~([\\][.]) | [\\][btnrf"\] )` but the `~` only negates a single character as far as I can tell. I get the error:

> error AC0050: extraneous input '[.]' expecting RPAREN while looking for lexer rule element

It seems like it shouldn't be too hard to exclude `\*` but allow the small list of acceptable escaped characters. I have been on http://www.regex101.com and I don't have any trouble matching the allowable characters, but for some reason I just can't figure out how to disallow escape characters besides the ones mentioned above, while also allowing all other characters.

Manually specifying every valid input character seems like overkill, but that may be what it comes down to. Something like:

`[a-ZA-Z0-9_!@#$%^&*()\-+=/.,<>;':\b\t\n\r\f\"\\]*`

That may not be 100% valid, but the idea is just listing all valid possible characters, which by default would exclude any invalid escape characters. It seems like there should be a simpler way. Any tips or links to useful information would greatly appreciated.

The actual rule that I have so far, which allows anything enclosed in double quotes as a valid string:

```
STRING : '"' (~[\"] | '\\"')* '"';
```

Comment: What I don't understand is , which characters are you trying to negate?

Comment: I am trying to allow all regular characters and disallow all escaped characters except for the ones mentioned. So `\t` or `\"` are valid, but `\u` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have ANTLR handy, but the following seems to do what you're after :

```
\([^\\].\)\|\(\\[btnrf\\"\\\\]\)
```

so effectively allow "EITHER anything other than a backslash followed by any character, OR a backslash followed by a specified character".

eg, putting that string in a file regexfile, and given a datafile containing

```
\a
\b
\\
xy
```

then performing `grep -f regexfile datafile` will exclude the \a, and return :

```
\b
\\
xy
```

Comment: ah, this is exactly what I was looking for.. I just have to modify it ever so slightly to ANTLR syntax, and should be good to go, thanks!

Comment: one minor issue I ran into, double quotes are not legal UNLESS preceded by a backslash. I tried adding `[^"]` in place of the `.`, but it doesn't seem to be working properly